# how to delete an object while SaveOrUpdate in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, collections, insert-update, cascading-deletes

I have a collection of B's nested in an object of A ,and also i have 3 rows of B in database.First of all i fetch all 3 B in my grid view, and i delete 2 B there now i want to execute save Or Update method for A(all B's are nested in A).
For save Or Update method i send just 1 B(2 B was deleted in grid as i said). How can I delete those 2 B in table B just Using save Or Update method for A.

```
public class B implements java.io.Serializable {
    private int id;
    private A a;
    private String name;
    //getters and setters
}

public class A implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Set Bs = new HashSet(0);
}
```

Thank you.